# How do I remove duplicate and/or unwanted directories from ~/Library/Mobile Documents?

Tags: macos, icloud, mojave

I know that there are similar questions, but I could not find one that asked about this, specifically. I am running Mojave (10.14.6) on a 2017 iMac 27/5K. In the ~/Library/Mobile Documents directory, I have several directories that are either for iOS applications

1. I no longer use/have deleted, and/or
2. I still use, but for which there is at least one (in some cases more) duplicate.

Two examples are in the screenshot, below:

[image]

When I try to remove these directories, they almost instantly reappear.

How do I permanently remove these unwanted and unneeded directories?

Comment: Are those folders showing some occupancy in iCloud preferences, under manage storage tab ? System Preferences is being talked about.

Comment: Unfortunately, no